# Product of real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functions

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. What is $fg$? Is it function  $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}$?

For example, taking $n=2$ let $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2+x_1x_2$ and $g(y_1,y_2)=y_1+y_2-y_1^2 y_2^3$ we see that $fg:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone explain this confusing moment to me in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, then $fg : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$. It is key here that the codomains of $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb{R}$ where it makes sense to multiply elements.

In your example, $fg : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by

$$(fg)(x_1, x_2) = f(x_1, x_2)g(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 + x_2 + x_1x_2)(x_1 + x_2 - x_1^2x_2^3).$$

Comment: Is it definition of product multivariable functions? P.S. What's wrong with my example?

Comment: In my example, the variables of function $g$ are $y_1, y_2$ not $x_1,x_2$ as you wrote

Comment: It doesn't matter that you called them $y_1$ and $y_2$, the function $g$ is the same.

Comment: Why? If I wrote $g$ in terms of $y$ then $(fg)(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=(x_1+x_2+x_1x_2)(y_1+y_2-y_1^2y_2^3)$ is obviously function which domain is $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Sure, but it is not $fg$. You made up a function which is not what $fg$ denotes.

Comment: So how to define $fg$? One more question: 
What is the function that I made up​​? I am about $f(x)g(y)$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'how to define $fg$', that's what I said in my answer. I'm not sure there is a compact way to name the function you wrote.

Comment: Thanks! Just now I understand it!